# SVG onmouseover for CSS

Tags: javascript, css, svg, onmouseover

Is it possible to use the onmouseover(evt) thing in SVG to trigger a Javascript (ecmascript) that manipulates CSS rather than just SVG?

So for example I want the SVG to detect when I hover over a part of the screen, but then have some javascript NOT change SVG attributes but CSS things like 'font-size'.

I know this isn't a great explanation, but I'm really tired and weak.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: +1 why not try it yourself?

Comment: Thanks that's all I needed to know.